# How does EF4 determines if a property has really changed?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I need a way to track modified properties and audit them.
I am hooking into SaveChanges where I get the modified properties

```
   //Get only Modified Customer entries
   var modifiedCustomerOses = context.ObjectStateManager
     .GetObjectStateEntries<Customer>(EntityState.Modified)
     .ToList();
```

What I have noticed and I am using EF4 with codeGeneration that it reports when a property is not really modified as modified.
If a property EG "CustomerName" is set to "John" and when I do an update I dont change the name but I do 
EntityCustomer.Name=customerDto.Name and the name are exactly the same it still reports as changed.

I have looked at the generated code and cannot see if EF property does a check like

if(name==value)//propertyNotchanged dont raiseevent.

Any suggestions? Do you know how EF4 determines if a property has really changed?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tracking is performed on entity level, not on property level.
The more appropriate way to trace if the property was changed is to use the [OnPropertyChanged partial method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716747.aspx).
Just create a custom code that will hold the changed properties.